# Tomcat+QuerCus+Wordpress Pretty URLS

Tags: wordpress, tomcat, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, quercus

[Wordpress Permalinks on Quercus + Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385853/wordpress-permalinks-on-quercus-tomcat)

the solution described in the above post works, but the URL appears as

http://www.mysite.co.uk/blog/sample-post/?q=sample-post

How do we avoid the last bit "q=sample-post" from appearing? Removing the code from the program doesn't help!

Please advise.